# Is there a way to finalize all animations on a powerpoint slide?

Tags: powerpoint

Quite often when showing a slide deck in PowerPoint, there is not time enough to show all animations on each slide. Is there a way to show all animations in their final state? I have googled without any success, so my final hope is that someone has done a VB script for this. (Or even better - if there is built-in functionality for this that I have not found...)
Note: I do not want to skip to next slide, just show the slide as it would be shown right before stepping to next slide.

Answer (score 0):

What I do with my presenteations is I use the clicks or spaces or whatever to make each animation/next move happen, so if you can use that as a feature maybe it will help.

I simply press the button many times and the animations start and end quickly for the next one to take place.

Comment: It is of course one option, but this is what I would like to avoid... There is a high risk of clicking one too much, and then you need to go backards to show the right slide... A bit unprofessional in my view...

Comment: I accept your point of view. However using more slides with less animation, rather than one slide with many of them might do the trick. I have encountered your problem too, and this was the best I could come across with. Hope you solve your problem though.